# "mapping value" error with rosinstall

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I'm just installing ROS on my new squeeze Debian following installation guide I find some issue due launching command:

> http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no

This is my output:

> rosinstall operating on /home/laux/ros from specifications in rosinstall files  http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no
>
> ahhhhhhhh, yaml parse error: mapping values are not allowed here
> in "", line 5, column 8
> Usage: rosinstall PATH [ ...] [URI]...
>
> rosinstall: error: None

Has anyone any idea about my problem?

Thanks
Laux

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9678/%22mapping-value%22-error-with-rosinstall/) by [Laux](https://answers.ros.org/users/403/laux/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered this same problem yesterday, and submitted a [bug report](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3451). It is fixed now though, so you can just try again.

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2011-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3